# Show rows from a tab when a column header matches a string and the cells in that column contain a specified value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with a spreadsheet where the columns are consistently in flux and I am not sure where a specific column might end up any given day.

We use this sheet to track replies to outreach campaigns and when a specific account/row replies to us, we put a 'Y' in that same rows 'Replied?' column. The 'Replied?' column will move over time but the name will always stay the same.

I am therefore curious if there is a way to Query/Filter or even use a script to return all rows where the row has a 'Y' in the 'Replied?' column.

When the 'Replied?' column was always fixed in Col32 we were able to use the QUERY function to return the desired results.

```
=QUERY({'Mike Master Sheet'!A2:AG;'Mark Master Sheet'!A2:AG},"Select * where Col32 = 'Y' order by Col33")
```

But now that the 'Replied?' column is going to be changing columns we need to come up with a way to query by column header name rather than index.

I do not think the QUERY function is flexible like this, but is there a script that could achieve this?

If the data set was as follows;

```
ID    | customer_name | Replied?
________________________________
0101  | Mike          |
0201  | Tessa         |  Y
0301  | Melanie       |
```

I would want it to return row 2 under ID `0201` because the name of that column = `Replied?` and the row in that column = `Y`

Comment: Coul you try the answer below and let me know whether it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your original query to get the column which has `Replied?` in the first row:

```
=QUERY({'Mike Master Sheet'!A2:AG;'Mark Master Sheet'!A2:AG},"Select * where "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Replied?",'Mark Master Sheet'!A1:AG1,0),4),1,"")& " = 'Y' order by Col33")
```

Comment: Hey! I tweaked this a bit and was able to make it work, thanks a ton for this solution, its much more elegant than going to a script and it is very creative! Here is what I ended up tweaking too;
```=QUERY({'Mike Master Sheet'!A1:AO},"Select * where Col"&SUBSTITUTE(MATCH("replied?",'Mike Master Sheet'!A1:AO1,0),1,"")&"='Y'")```

I am going to also build in referencing other peoples sheets, but have not gotten there yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function movingHeaders(s,v) {//s is the header title for the column your searching in v is the value your looking for
  var s=s||'Replied?';
  var v=v||'Y';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet172');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var hA=vA[0];
  var hObj={};
  var result=[];//result is the array of rows that meet the search requirements
  for(var i=0;i<hA.length;i++) {
    hObj[hA[i]]=i;
  }
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][hObj[s]]==v) {
      result.push(vA[i]); 
    }
  }
  Logger.log(result);
}
```